# Difference between type reference of member function and the same static version

Tags: types, typescript

There are two ways to to the same thing in the code below, using static method and using member funciton. Both of them use generics, but member function just delegates all work to the static version. The thing is that compiler does different type inference.

I asked very similar question but my explanation was awful : [wrong type inference with generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23474209/wrong-type-inference-with-generics).

```
class channel<S,Y> {

static flatMapImpl<T,R>(self: channel<any, T>, projector:(t:T) => channel<T,R>) {
    var ch = new channel<T, R>();

    return ch;  
}

public flatMap<R>(projector: (data: Y) => channel<Y, R>) {
    return channel.flatMapImpl(this, projector);
}

public merge2(...targets: channel<any, Y>[]) {
    var ch = new channel<void, channel<any, Y>>().named('merge');
    var r = channel.flatMapImpl(ch, x => x); // fine !

    return r;
}

public merge(...targets: channel<any, Y>[]) {
    var ch = new channel<void, channel<any, Y>>().named('merge');
    var result = ch.flatMap(x => x); // <-- compilation error

    return result;
}
}
```

Look at the code = flatMap is implemented via flatMapImpl and has the same return type.
merge has almost identical code, the only diffenrence is flatMap and flatMapImpl.

The question is - why the second version can't be compiled and how to fix it ?

Of course, I can set some annotation such as , but, actually, the member function is the main use case. That means that I will have to put annotations or etc. to every call.

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense... 1. The method `flatMapImpl` does not use any of the parameters it receives, so what's the point? 2. When you call `flatMap` and `flatMapImpl` you pass `x => x` even though neither of these methods are defined to receive such a method

Comment: 1 The point is to show the typisation, not the implementation 2 dont understand this point

Comment: `x => x` is `function(x) { return x; }`, and you pass that to `flatMap` and `flatMapImpl` but neither of them excepts such a type, what they do expect is `(Y) => channel<Y, R>`